# How do I select this particular class in my code?

Tags: css, stylesheet

```
<div class="one-545">
    <div class="two"></div>
    <div class="three">
        <div class="four">
            <div class="five">
                <div class="six"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

This is what my code looks like. I basically, want to select the class "six". However, there are other "six" classes on the page. But I want to only select the "six" class which is in "one-545" class. 545 is basically a randomly generated number which is different from other such codes on the page.
I have tried this, but it doesnt work:

```
.one-545 .six
```

So how else can I select the "six" class which is in "one-545"?

Comment: you can select parent container and apply in child selector but `.one-545 .six` that will works 100%

Comment: If there are other `one-xxx` then you will need javascript but otherwise `[class^="one-"] .six` will work

Comment: `.one-545 .six` that you have tried is correct.

Answer (score 0):

```
.one-545 .six {
   /* your styles*/
}
```

Surely this will work.